# Merging problem in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, branching-and-merging

I have a problem merging what I think is two different heads in HG. When I update between the two revisions (512 and 502 in the screen shot) there are differences between the files. However when I try to merge 512 to 502 it says that there's nothing to merge. If I update to rev. 512 and try to merge 502 to 512 I get the following error message instead: "merging with a working directory ancestor has no effect". Judging by the error message it looks like 502 is a parent of 512 but based on the graph they look like two different heads. What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding?

[image: Screen shot from TortoiseHG]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> but based on the graph they look like
>   two different heads. What am I doing
>   wrong or misunderstanding

The graph pretty clearly shows that 502 isn't a head at all, right there in red.  Your view is filtering away changesets, changesets that must show that 502 is an ancestor of 512.

Can you disable the filter and re-post the image, or better yet provide the output of the command line `hg glog` command?

Worst case you can `hg update 502` commit a do-nothing change, whose parent is 502, and then merge that with 512, but you're better off getting the full picture/understanding of what's going on.

Comment: +1 regarding incomplete graph. 503 through 509 are not shown in the graph, but such numbers are always sequential.

Comment: You're completely right! When I removed the filter I saw that 502 had been merged into another branch and then that branch had been merged into Default, which created rev. 510. Thanks!